# Is there a way to pass an extra value to the panic handler?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a UEFI OS loader, and I use the system table provided by `efi_main` in the panic handler to print a string on the console. Currently, I'm using a global static variable and a helper function to access it like this:

```rust
static SYSTEM_TABLE_WRAPPER: Lazy<Spinlock<Option<SystemTable>>> =
    Lazy::new(|| Spinlock::new(None));

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(i: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    // SAFETY: The existing lock is forgotten. There is no way to access the lock from the panic
    // handler.
    unsafe { unlock_system_table() }

    error!("{}", i);

    loop {
        x86_64::instructions::hlt();
    }
}

pub fn _print(args: fmt::Arguments<'_>) {
    let mut st = crate::system_table();
    let mut stdout = st.con_out();

    let _ = stdout.write_fmt(args);
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! println {
    () => {
        $crate::print!("\n");
    };
    ($($arg:tt)*)=>{
        $crate::print!("{}\n",core::format_args!($($arg)*));
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! print {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {
        $crate::io::_print(core::format_args!($($arg)*));
    };
}

pub(crate) fn system_table<'a>() -> MappedSpinlockGuard<'a, uefi_wrapper::SystemTable> {
    let st = SYSTEM_TABLE_WRAPPER.try_lock();
    let st = st.expect("Failed to lock the global System Table.");

    SpinlockGuard::map(st, |st| {
        let st = st.as_mut();
        let st = st.expect("The global System Table is not initialized.");
        &mut st.0
    })
}
```

Although this works correctly, I'd like to avoid using any global variables if possible. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there seems to be no way to do that, I changed the way.
Firstly, I defined the `uefi_print` and `uefi_println` macros.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! uefi_print{
    ($st:expr,$($arg:tt)*)=>{
        $crate::io::_print($st,format_args!($($arg)*));
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! uefi_println {
    ($st:expr) => {
        $crate::uefi_print!($st,"\n");
    };
    ($st:expr,$($arg:tt)*)=>{
        $crate::uefi_print!($st,"{}\n",format_args!($($arg)*));
    }
}

#[doc(hidden)]
pub fn _print(st: &mut crate::SystemTable, args: fmt::Arguments<'_>) {
    let mut con_out = st.con_out();

    let _ = con_out.write_fmt(args);
}
```

These macros are similar to `print` and `println` macros, but the first parameter is the mutable reference to `SystemTable`. The example macro invocation:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "win64" fn efi_main(h: uefi_wrapper::Handle, mut st: bootx64::SystemTable) -> ! {
    let resolution = gop::set_preferred_resolution(&mut st);
    uefi_println!(&mut st, "GOP info: {:?}", resolution,);
    // ...
}
```

Secondly, I defined the `uefi_panic` macro:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! uefi_panic {
    ($st:expr) => {
        $crate::uefi_panic!($st, "explicit panic");
    };
    ($st:expr,$($t:tt)+)=>{
        $crate::uefi_println!($st,"panicked at '{}', {}:{}:{}",core::format_args!($($t)+),file!(),line!(),column!());
        panic!();
    }
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    loop {
        x86_64::instructions::hlt();
    }
}
```

The first parameter of the macro is also the mutable reference to `SystemTable`.

Thirdly, I defined a wrapper type for `SystemTable` that defines the additional method `expect_ok`.

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SystemTable(uefi_wrapper::SystemTable);
impl SystemTable {
    // ...

    /// # Panics
    ///
    /// This method panics if `result` is [`Err`].
    pub fn expect_ok<T, E: fmt::Debug>(&mut self, result: Result<T, E>, msg: &str) -> T {
        match result {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(e) => {
                uefi_panic!(self, "{}: {:?}", msg, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I prefer this way to the previous method. The exit boot services function can move the ownership of `SystemTable` and `ImageHandle`. This way prevents these types from being used after calling it. After all, I should not create a global static `SystemTable` since it won't be valid after exiting the boot services.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so. If its possible, any parameter would be a global as well. Making it more complex.

Global variables are ok for this. Create your own global panic object and give it to a new panic handler from the real one.